# How to add buttons to NowPlayingView of Apple Watch using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, watchos

The `NowPlayingView` is a structure. We can use it like:

```
NowPlayingView()
```

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/nowplayingview)

> Don’t add any other elements to the view.

We, developer can not add anything to the view.

But the Apple Music and Podcast's `NowPlayingView` are different.

Apple Music `NowPlayingView`:

[image]

Podcast `NowPlayingView`:

[image]

So I want to know if there any chance we can customize the `NowPlayingView`.

Comment: I think it is impossible, but I am not sure, it is kind of luck screen of iPhone when something playing in background. you can not overwrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple's Engineer, developers can not change anything on NowPlayingView.
Additionally, the bottom-right menu button is neither not available to developers.

Reference:
[Can not modify NowPlayingView](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670911). [Can not use menu button](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670864)